# Blueimp jQuery multiple fileupload plugin $(this).fileupload() not a function

Tags: blueimp

Am using blueimp jQuery plugin for multiple fileupload for my web application in struts framework, but the problem is fileupload handler is not getting initialized by jQuery. I am getting $('#fileupload').fileupload not a function. Can any one help me to figure out where I am going wrong.

```
`<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link href="css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/jquery.fileupload-ui-noscript.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.postmessage-transport.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
.bar {
    height: 18px;
    background: green;
}
</style>
<head>
<body>
<form id="fileupload" action="testAction.do?operation=uploadImages" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<noscript><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/"></noscript>
    <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
        <div class="span7">
            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
                <span>Add files...</span>
                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
            </span>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                <span>Start upload</span>
            </button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                <span>Cancel upload</span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                <span>Delete</span>
            </button>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            <span class="fileupload-loading"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="span5 fileupload-progress fade">
            <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                <div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>
</form>
<br>

<div id="progress">
    <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
</div>

<script>
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
        });
    }
});
});
</script> 
</body> 
</html>`
```

Answer (score 9):

You have to make sure that you are loading all the script files in the correct order:

```
jquery.ui.widget.js
jquery.iframe-transport.js
jquery.fileupload.js
```

just before you close the body tag.

Also, use the browser inspector the see that the scripts are actually loading.

Comment: Hello, i'm having this problem as well, but i've already added thos tags, and it still saying "is not a function". I'm using laravel 5 and in the web tools doesn't say anything about those files, only the is not a function problem. Im going nuts!

Comment: You can see if it's loading in the network tab in the browser inspector - check the error code - if you get a 404 or something it's not actually loading.

Comment: Ok i finally made it work, i just changed the main.blade.php on Laravel, to a the scripts to the very bottom. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 1):

I think you must include a jquery ui first then jquery file upload

```
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
```

That fixing my error like you mentioned above